# ElasticSearch persian word split

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two words for example
1." دارو خانه عباسی"
2."داروخانه عباسی"

when I search
"query": {
"match": {
"title": "داروخانه"
}
}
my result is just number 2 but i want to show tow words
how do I search?
thanks

Comment: My reading of Arabic script is very limited, does the word appear in both entries?

Comment: No, there is a space between "دارو" and "خانه" that shouldn't be but I search "داروخانه" that I want to show both of "دارو خانه" and "داروخانه"

Comment: It might help others to answer if you could replicate the problem with a Latin text example.

Comment: for example you have "SmallDog" and "Small Dog", I'd like to search "Small Dog" and I expect that show both of them.not just "Small Dog"